# Validate @versionColumn value before saving an entity with TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm currently working on saving data in a postgres DB using TypeORM with the NestJS integration. I'm saving data which keeps track of a version property using TypeORM's [@VersionColumn](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/versioncolumn) feature, which increments a number each time `save()` is called on a repository.

For my feature it is important to check this version number before updating the records.

**Important**

I know I could technically achieve this by retrieving the record before updating it and checking the versions, but this leaves a small window for errors. If a 2nd user updates the same record in that millisecond between the get and save or if it would take longer for some weird reason, it would up the version and make the data in the first call invalid. TypeORM doesn't check the version value, so even if a call has a lower value than what is in the database, it still saves the data eventhough it should be seen as out of date.

```
1: User A checks latest version => TypeORM gives back the latest version: 1

2: User B updates record => TypeORM ups the version: 2

3: User A saves their data with version 1     <-- This needs to validate the versions first.

4: TypeORM  overwrites User B's record with User A's data
```

What I'm looking for is a way to make TypeORM decline step 3 as the latest version in the database is 2 and User A tries to save with version 1.

I've tried using the querybuilder and update statements to make this work, but the build-in @VersionColumn only up the version on every `save()` call from a repository or entity manager.

Besides this I also got a tip to look into database triggers, but as far as  I could find, this feature is [not yet supported](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1082) by TypeORM

Here is an example of the setup:

```
async update(entity: Foo): Promise<boolean> {

  const value = await this._configurationRepository.save(entity);

  if (value === entity) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: How are you currently managing migrations for your schema changes? Are you letting them be autogenerated? This would be trivial to implement using a trigger in the DB that is reusable across any table that has a version column

Comment: We are looking into managing our migrations manually instead of automatically generating them

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, something like this is much better served through triggers directly in the Database as it will fix concerns around race conditions as well as making it so that modifications made outside the ORM will also update the version number. Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3f5fa6/1) demonstrating triggers in action. You'll just need to incorporate it into your schema migrations.

Here is the relevant DDL from the SQL Fiddle example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE entity_1
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    some_value text,
    version int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_version() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    NEW.version = NEW.version + 1;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER increment_entity_1_version
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON entity_1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE increment_version();
```

The same trigger function can be used for any table that has a `version` column in case this is a pattern you want to use across multiple tables.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks for your input. As linked in the question, I found no information about how TypeORM supports triggers. Do I need to change my TypeORM setup to be able to do this, or is there a work around that does allow you to use triggers with TypeORM?

Comment: Also, am I correct when I say that this trigger only increments the version value? This is already handled by the @ValueColumn. I'm only looking for a way to check the incoming version value, check if it is equal to the value in the database and if isn't, abort the update.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for concurrency control. If this is the case there is a solution in this about 1/2 the way down. [TypeORM concurrency control issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3608)